# Report to get difference in SQL Agent jobs across nodes in Availability Group

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, jobs

Is there a script or an article out there to check differences between SQL Agent jobs across nodes in AG and create a report based on the difference? I am not looking for dbatools.io as it syncs the job based on 'last modified or create date'. I am also not looking to sync jobs. I am just looking for some report that would identify the difference in both SQL jobs. For example, if a parameter was different or if a job is enabled or not.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DBA Dash](https://dbadash.com/) has a job schema diff tool that can report on the job difference between two servers.  It also captures snapshots of your agent job DDL, providing a history of changes.

DBA Dash is a free and open-source monitoring tool for SQL Server, created by me.  The job schema diff is just a small part of what the tool does.  Great if you need a monitoring tool that can also do a job diff between servers.

If you are not interested in a monitoring tool you might be able to use something like [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/) (Or SQL Server SMO)  to extract the Job DDL to the file system - using a folder for each server.  Then use a diff tool like [DiffMerge](https://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) to compare the two folders.

Edit:
I also created [this script](https://wisedataman.com/how-to-handle-sql-agent-jobs-with-always-on-availability-groups) which can be used to sync jobs.  If you pass -DoSync it will sync the jobs otherwise it will report the differences.  It only reports that the jobs are different rather than showing a schema diff like DBA Dash, but you could use this script as a starting point for exporting the job DDL and using a compare tool.

Hope this helps.
[image: DBA Dash Job schema diff]

Answer (score -1):

```
-- Query for Node 1
USE msdb;
SELECT 
    j1.name AS JobName,
    CASE WHEN j1.enabled = 1 THEN 'Enabled' ELSE 'Disabled' END AS Status,
    j1.category_id AS Category
FROM dbo.sysjobs j1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    -- Check if the job exists on Node 2 and has the same attributes
    SELECT 1
    FROM Node2.msdb.dbo.sysjobs j2
    WHERE j1.job_id = j2.job_id
        AND j1.enabled = j2.enabled
        AND j1.category_id = j2.category_id
);

-- Query for Node 2
USE msdb;
SELECT 
    j2.name AS JobName,
    CASE WHEN j2.enabled = 1 THEN 'Enabled' ELSE 'Disabled' END AS Status,
    j2.category_id AS Category
FROM dbo.sysjobs j2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    -- Check if the job exists on Node 1 and has the same attributes
    SELECT 1
    FROM Node1.msdb.dbo.sysjobs j1
    WHERE j2.job_id = j1.job_id
        AND j2.enabled = j1.enabled
        AND j2.category_id = j1.category_id
);
```